# Distribution of the difference of order statistics

Tags: uniform-distribution

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be a random sample of size 2 from a uniform distribution over the interval $[0,1]$, let $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ be the corresponding order statistics. Find

1. the conditional density function of $Y_1$ given $Y_2$
2. the probability density function of $Y_2-Y_1$

I first had to find the order statistics of $Y_1$ which is $2(1-y)$ and of $Y_2$ which is $2y$. In both cases $0<y<1$.
Should I use these two to find (1.)?

I also feel (2.) can only be done using convolution theorem of discrete random variables.
Am I in the right direction?

Comment: Does order statistics mean that $Y_1=\min(X_1,X_2)$ and $Y_2=\max(X_1,X_2)$?

Comment: Since n=2, I took Y1 to be the minimum order statistics and Y2 to be the maximum order statistic

Comment: You can find the necessary knowledge here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic

Comment: $Y_2-Y_1=|X_1-X_2|$, so question #2 can be done as shown here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1681363/321264.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We will need the joint comulatice distribution function $F_{Y_1,Y_2}(u,v)=P(Y_1<u,Y_2<v).$

Now,

$$P(Y_1<u,Y_2<v)=P(Y_1<u,Y_2<v, X_1\le X_2)+P(Y_1<u,Y_2<v ,X_2<X_1)=$$
$$=P(X_1<u,X_2<v, X_1\le X_2)+P(X_2<u,X_1<v ,X_2<X_1).$$

First,
$$P(X_1<u,X_2<v, X_1\le X_2)=
\begin{cases}
-\frac{u^2}{2}+uv,&\text{ if }& 0\le u\le v \le 1\\
\frac{v^2}{2},&\text{ if }& 0\le v<u \le1
\end{cases}.$$

The figure below explains how I calculated the two pieces of surface area:

[image]

Second,

$$P(X_2<u,X_1<v ,X_2<X_1)=P(X_2<u,X_1<v, X_2\le X_1)=
\begin{cases}
-\frac{u^2}{2}+uv
,&\text{ if }& 0\le u\le v \le 1\\
\frac{v^2}{2},&\text{ if }& 0\le v<u \le1
\end{cases}.$$
(A figure similar to the one above would explain the latter result.)
We can calculate the joint cdf:
$$F_{Y_1,Y_2}(u,v)=$$$$=P(X_1<u,X_2<v, X_1\le X_2)+P(X_2<u,X_1<v ,X_2<X_1)=$$

### $$=\begin{cases}
-u^2+2uv,&\text{ if }& 0\le u\le v \le 1\\
v^2,&\text{ if }& 0\le v<u \le1
\end{cases}.$$

The joint pdf can be calculated the following way:
$$f_{Y_1,Y_2}(u,v)=\frac{{\partial} ^2}{\partial u \partial v}F_{Y_1,Y_2}(u,v)=\begin{cases}
2,&\text{ if }& 0\le u\le v \le 1\\
0,&\text{ otherwise. }
\end{cases}$$

---

Then we will need the following marginal density:

### $$f_{Y_2}(v)=\int_0^vf_{Y_1,Y_2}(u,v)du=2\int_0^v\ du=2v;\  0\le v\le 1.$$

To answer the first question: By definition

### $$f_{Y_1 \mid Y_2=v}(u)=\frac{f_{Y_1,Y_2}(u,v)}{f_{Y_2}(v)}=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{v},&\text{ if }& 0\le u\le v \le 1\\
0,&\text{ else. }
\end{cases} \tag 1$$

To answer the second question: First let's calculate the cdf of $Y_2-Y_1$. By definition

$$F_{Y_2-Y_1}(x)=P(Y_2-Y_1<x)=E[P(Y_2-Y_1<x \mid Y_2)]. $$

Then

$$P(Y_2-Y_1<x \mid Y_2=v)=
\begin{cases}
0,&\text{ if } x<0\\
P(Y_1>v-x\mid Y_2=v),& \text{ if } 0\le x \le v \le 1\\
1,&\text{ if } x>v
\end{cases}$$

where $0\le v \le 1$.

Considering $(1)$ we have for $0\le x \le v \le 1$

$$P(Y_1>v-x\mid Y_2=v)=\frac 1v\int_{v-x}^v\ du=\frac xv.$$

So, for a given $0\le x \le 1$

$$P(Y_2-Y_1<x \mid Y_2=v)=\begin{cases}
1,& \text{ if } 0\le v\le x\\
\frac xv,&\text{ if } x\le v\le 1.\\
\end{cases}$$

As a result, for $0\le x \le 1$

$$F_{Y_2-Y_1}(x)=\int_0^1P(Y_2-Y_1<x \mid Y_2=v)f_{Y_2}(v)\ dv=$$
$$=2\int_0^x v \ dv + 2x\int_x^1 \ dv=2x-x^2.$$

Finally, $$f_{Y_2-Y_1}(x)=\begin{cases}
2-2x,& \text{ if } 0\le x \le 1 \\
0,&\text{ otherwise. }
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Not very clear on second question from second step to third step

Comment: @DOCTORNGILAZIBANDAJOSHUA: I will have to "reunderstand" the whole thing again. Please, give me some time.

Comment: @DOCTORNGILAZIBANDAJOSHUA: I've found an error. (Sorry.) I am working on the fix.

Comment: @DOCTORNGILAZIBANDAJOSHUA, I've edited my answer.

Comment: @ zoli,Thank you very much for your help